# Font awesome and bootstrap button with icons syntax

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

In bootstrap, buttons with icons are implemented using a combination of `<button>` and `<span>`:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-examples

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

In font awesome, buttons are implemented using combination of `<a>` and `<i>`:

http://fontawesome.io/examples/

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i> Delete</a>
```

Is there a better way? Or are the selection of these tags completely arbitrary?

Comment: Actually in bootstrap you can use <a> and <i> too, as long as they have correct classes like `<a class="btn btn-default"` and `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It completely depends upon the usage.

In bootstrap you can implement buttons using combination of `<a>` and `<i>`. Similarly , in font-awesome buttons with icons can be implemented using a combination of `<button>` and `<span>`.

For example: If we need to submit a form and the submit button contains a font-awesome icon then we do it like this--

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
 <span class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></span>
 </button>
```

Another example: If we need to use a normal link and the link contains a bootstrap glyphicon icon then we can do it like this--

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></i> Delete</a>
```

Comment: For most buttons you'll want the icons to be fixed-width so all of your icon-buttons appear the same size. Add the `fa-fw` class to accomplish this.

Answer (score 15):

Another example using `<i>` tag.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button  class="btn btn-warning">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i>
</button>
    
<button  class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i> Delete
</button>

<button  class="btn btn-danger">
    Delete <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i> 
</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Glyphicon Examples</h2>
  <p>Envelope icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></p>    
  <p>Envelope icon as a link:
    <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a>
  </p>
  <p>Search icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></p>
  <p>Search icon on a button:
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
    </button>
  </p>
  <p>Search icon on a styled button:
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
    </button>
  </p>
  <p>Print icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></p>      
  <p>Print icon on a styled link button:
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span> Print 
    </a>
  </p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.